# How to make an Microsoft Access data entry form with multiple linked tables

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

Complicated question based on a personal project, but if there was any thoughts or tips would be much appreciated. I am still relatively new to Microsoft Access and SQL.

I am having troubles with a Personal Project that I am working on.

I am trying to develop a QC Testing Database for my work.

There are a number of different products we produce, and they each have a set of tests that have to be performed on a production Lot. The tests vary depending on the product.

The database would have a form for the Test Report, that would allow a user to go in and select the product they are testing. Ideally that would have a sub form that shows all the tests they have to perform, and then a box next to each to enter the results of each test. The operator could then and make a QC Test report that can be saved as a pdf.

**My biggest issue is creating a form to enter in new data.** I want the specific tests to show up based on the product they choose, and then be able to enter results tied to those tests.

I am able to enter in data into the tables manually, and make a form to view the data properly for each report.

As for tables I have:

Product table - unique table of all the products

Specification Tests table- unique table of all individual tests that have to be performed, as well as specification range for the results

Spec table - table that joins the product ID to all the specification tests that have to be performed

Report Table - table that creates a record for each report. This has

Result table - houses each unique test result.  Relates to specification test ID as well as the Report ID.

As for queries, I have:

Query that shows the specification tests required based on the product ID chosen.

As I said, I can enter in data to the tables manually, and have a form that allows me to go through each Test Report record and see the data properly.

Data entry is harder because the number of tests and the specific tests vary based on product.

I have a query that looks at the product Id selected by user, and lists the specification tests required. I tried to make a query using that query, and adding in a results field.
When I go to my main reports form, this sub form is completely empty.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsK7u.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzB9K.jpg)

Comment: You need a procedure to 'batch' create a set of test records for inputting the new data. This could involve an INSERT INTO SELECT action SQL. Fairly common topic. One recent example https://www.utteraccess.com/topics/2064252/posts/2808114

Comment: Can a specification associate with multiple products and each product have multiple specifications?